# System of PDE for diffusion-reaction system

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of PDE that describes how a concentration of a molecule $M_1$ will diffusion (and disappears) through time at a fixe position ($x=0$). The molecule does not follow a simple Fick's law since at the $x=0$ position there is another molecule $M_2$, that cannot move, but that may influence the diffusion of $M_1$. You can find my system in the picture attached and below:
[attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuNHZ.png)
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial t} = -2D\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial z^2}  \right) -\alpha f_1\cdot f_2 + \beta f_3\\
\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial t} = -\alpha f_1\cdot f_2 + \beta f_3\\
\dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial t} = \alpha f_1\cdot f_2 - \beta f_3
\end{cases}
$$
where $D$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, and the initial-boundary conditions are expressed by the following relations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\left.\begin{pmatrix} 
f_1(t) \\
f_2(t) \\
f_3(t) 
\end{pmatrix}\right|_{t=0} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A \\
B \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\left.\begin{pmatrix} 
f_1(t) \\
f_2(t) \\
f_3(t) 
\end{pmatrix}\right|_{t=t_\text{final}} \!\!\!\!\!= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
B \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{cases}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some constants.

I have already tried different things such as solving with linear algebra (by finding the eigenvalue and eigenvector) but it did not help. Probably because it is a PDE and I have two dependent equation. I have also tried to non dimensionalized the question but it did not help me to find a was through the solution. Thanks for your help and have a nice day

Comment: this is a nonlinear set of equations, it's not likely that you will be able to find a closed-form solution.

Comment: Do you want the opposite sign for the diffusion term?

Comment: Yes I need the minus sign to describe what's happening in the system